# Differences between entity manager and repository typeorm

Tags: node.js, typeorm

I don't understand the differences between Entity manager and Repository in typeorm. They seem to do the same thing. If it's the same, why two different API exists. If not what are the differences and when we use them.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

An Entity Manager handles all entities, while Repository handles a single entity. This means that when using an Entity Manager you have to specify the Entity you are working with for each method call.

Here is an example of a create method from the [Entity Manager](https://typeorm.io/#/entity-manager-api) and [Repository](https://typeorm.io/#/repository-api) documentation for comparison:

```
const manager = getManager();
// ...
const user = manager.create(User); // same as const user = new User();

const repository = connection.getRepository(User);
// ...
const user = repository.create(); // same as const user = new User();
```

Both are valid and you can choose whichever you prefer to work with.

Comment: Are there any other differences? e.g. performance?

Answer (score 4):

It does exactly the same thing just an [alias](https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/issues/1671)

either you do

**Option 1:**

```
const manager = getManager();
manager.find(Methodology);
manager.find(Infrastructure);
manager.find(Safety);
```

**Option 2:**

```
getRepository(Methodology).find();
getRepository(Infrastructure).find();
getRepository(Safety).find();
```